# Why does this Java long calculation return NaN?

Tags: java, long-integer, nan

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main (final String[] args) {
        float distanceInMeters = 0.0f;
        long time = 1439230171182L;
        long previousTime = 1439230111554L;
        float speed = (distanceInMeters / 1000) / ((time - previousTime)/3600000);
        System.out.println(speed);
    }
}
```

This calculation returns "NaN". Does anyone know why?

Comment: Why are people down-voting this question? The asker posts code that reproduces the issue and tells us what the issue is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're dividing by zero always. You're subtracting two longs then doing integer division. Those two longs will be less than 3600000, so your result will be `(distanceInMeters / 1000) / 0` = `NaN`

Comment: So basically there is just a missing cast to float. Thanks for the answer. The solution is to write `float speed = (distanceInMeters / 1000) / ((float)(time - previousTime)/3600000);`

Comment: You can also just explicitly write `3600000F`

Comment: Yep. I don't like that my questions has gotten 2 down votes. Everyone can forget about Integer division in Java -.- Especially when you had to write JavaScript for some time.

Comment: @teddy3D I downvoted because this is something really simple you could have debugged yourself.

Comment: @Trobbins That is what I have done but whatever I did the console just told me the result is NaN.

Comment: @teddy3D then you should have broken your math up into separate lines and observed each operation.

Comment: I guess debuggers are out of fashion nowadays.

Comment: This question is perfectly appropriate for StackOverflow. Because the poster does not have the techniques developed to find the answer himself is not a reason for downvoting. He made an effort, posted code, explained the problem, and sought help.

Answer (score 5):

Lets put some our values and calculate it:

```
(distanceInMeters / 1000) / ((time - previousTime)/3600000);
```

is same as

```
(       0.0f      / 1000) / ((1439230171182L - 1439230111554L)/3600000)
```

`0.0f/1000 = 0.0f` and `1439230171182L - 1439230111554L = 59628L` so we get

```
(           0.0f        ) / ((           59628L              )/3600000)
```

`59628L/3600000` = `0` (integer division)

So we and up with `0.0f / 0` which is `NaN` (Not a Number).
If you would divide `1.0f / 0` you would get `Infinity` and for `-1.0f / 0` you would get `-Infinity`

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add a float cast like this:

```
float speed = (distanceInMeters / 1000) / ((float)(time - previousTime)/3600000);
```

or like this:

```
float speed = (distanceInMeters / 1000) / ((time - previousTime)/3600000.0f);
```

I forgot about the Integer division in Java. Probably because I wrote a lot of JavaScript code previously.